# C Prototype Function - object file

Tags: c, linux, elf, object-files, symbol-table

When compiling a c source file in Linux how a prototype function is treated? Is the symbol stored in the object file (formatted as ELF file) or a signature is stored to make reference to it when linking? 
For example:

```
#define MAX 32
typedef struct{
    float[3][3];
}Tensor_t;

float tensor_trace(Tensor_t* t);
```

Is "tensor_trace" allocated somwhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BTW, you need to give the `float` array a name.

If you compile the shown source as a C file an empty object file will be the result. No symbol will be stored.

If you use the shown source as a header file included in another C file which **does not** call `tensor_trace()`, the object file will have no symbol stored for it.

If you use the shown source as a header file included in another C file which **does** call `tensor_trace()`, the object file will have a symbol stored for it. At the place where the call is generated a reference to this symbol is placed. The linker will resolve this reference to the function which will have to be defined in another module.

So to answer your question:

> Is "tensor_trace" allocated somwhere?

The machine code for `tensor_trace()` will be "allocated" in the module that defines it. The declaration does **not** allocate any space.

Comment: It is the same thing with a defined type such as:  "typedef int bool" ?

Comment: Sure. This type definition is only used in the including translation unit. A type definition as such never uses space in allocated sections, only the variables defined with this type.